# How to draw diagrams in your blog?

Tags: plugins, html

There is number of plugins that use some third party drawing service... I don't like that!

I would like to be able to use html5 canvas features with some applications such as http://artisanjs.com/ something like what this guy did here http://www.owainlewis.com/blog/post/html5_canvas_drawing_application/

Ideally it should be integrated in TinyMCE....

Anyone?

Comment: Sounds more like you're looking for a TinyMCE plugin for drawing ... you might have more luck asking on StackOverflow. Also, since this isn't really a WordPress question, I'm tempted to migrate it to SO anyway.

Comment: yeah... if the move will increase the likelihood of getting the answer... go with it!

Comment: tinyMCE seems to be quite slow community....

Answer (score 2):

try Paint web

http://code.google.com/p/paintweb/

Demo
http://www.robodesign.ro/paintweb/trunk/demos/demo-tinymce.html